# What are the possible values ​of the angles of triangle $ABC$?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

> In a triangle $ABC$, let $AP$ be the bisector of $\angle BAC$ with $P$ on the side $BC$, and let $BQ$ be the bisector of $\angle ABC$ with $Q$ on the side $CA$.
> We know that $\angle BAC=60^\circ$ and that $AB + BP = AQ + QB$.
> What are the possible values ​​of the angles of triangle $ABC$?
>
> <sup>(Answer: $\angle ABC = 80^\circ, \angle BCA=40^\circ, \angle BAC=60^\circ$)</sup>

My progress:

[image]

The relationships I found:

$AQ+QB = AB+BP\implies b+x=c+a$

$\angle C = 120^\circ -2\theta$

Considering angle bisector $BQ$ of $\triangle ABC$: $\dfrac{c}{b}=\dfrac{AC}{d}$

Similarly considering $AP$: $\dfrac{c}{a}=\dfrac{b+d}{y}$

$\angle 60^\circ +\angle B+\angle C \implies \angle B+\angle C = 120^\circ$

$x = \dfrac{(b+d)\cdot c}{AC+c}$

$x^2  =\dfrac{(AC)c}{bd}$

From sine rule:

$\displaystyle\frac{\sin60}{AC}=\frac{\sin C}{c}=\frac{\sin2\theta}{b+d}=\frac{\sqrt3}{2AC}$

From cosine rule:

$c^2 = AC^2+BC^2-2\cdot AC\cdot BC\cdot \cos\angle C$

$AC^2 = c^2+BC^2-2c\cdot BC\cdot\cos2\theta$

...???

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h17469

Comment: @ACB thanks for link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Hints: As can be seen in figure there are two key points you have to show:

1- Q is on perpendicular bisector of BC.

2- Triangle BPI is isosceles.

This is only possible construction.Using bisectors theorem may help.